# Error while running spec on gauge v 1.0.7

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, automated-tests, getgauge

Error encountered:
Current gauge language runner is not compatible with gauge LSP. Some of the editing feature will not work as expected

Is it related to issue with gauge version and visual studio version (1.43.1).
[attached image includes versions of guage used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgHqD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgHqD.png)

Comment: screenshot says gauge version is `1.0.6`, whereas question says `1.0.7`. Please clarify.

You may also post/discuss this in https://spectrum.chat/gauge/general/?tab=posts

Comment: Hello Srikanth ,the version is1.0.7 ,please find attached updated one and thanks for suggesting the forum..i will post it there on wards